# Error checking after submit in partial view in a modal window

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a modal window which pops up on a button click and contains a partial view with a couple of fields and a submit button. On submit I add the data from the partial view into the database and redirect to the original view that generated the pop up. All of this works fine. However, now I want to do an error check (for uniqueness) in the controller action and display an error from the modal view.

Here is how i set up the modal window with the partial view inside of it

```
@Html.Kendo().Window().Name("CopyTaskWindow").Title("Copy Task").Modal(true).Width(400).Draggable().Iframe(false).Visible(false)

function onCopyClick(id) {
        var wnd = $("#CopyTaskWindow").data("kendoWindow");

        wnd.refresh({
            url: '@(Url.Action("CopyTaskRender", "Task"))',
            data: { id: id },
            iframe: true
        });
        wnd.center().open();
    }
```

Here is the partial View

```
model pManager.Models.CopyTaskModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CopyTask", "Task", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "copyTaskForm" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.TaskID)
        <div style="float: left; width: 48%;">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewTaskName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @(Html.EditorFor(model=>model.NewTaskName))
            </div>
         </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 48%;">
            <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectId)
                </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectId) 
                                .DataTextField("Name") 
                                .DataValueField("ID") 
                                .DataSource(ds => ds 
                                    .Read("GetProjectsList", "Project").ServerFiltering(true) 
                                    ) 
                                ) 
            </div>
     </div>
    <div align="center" class="btns-container">
          <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-update btn-update" href="#" onclick="$('#copyTaskForm').submit()" >
                    <span class="k-icon k-update"></span>
                    Copy Task
                </a>
                <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-cancel btn-cancel" href="#">
                    <span class="k-icon k-cancel"></span>
                    Cancel
                </a>
        </div>
 }
```

And here are the render function and the function that actually processes the data from the submitted partial view

```
 public ActionResult CopyTaskRender(int? id)
        {
            var context = new pcloudEntities();
            var tmp = context.Tasks.Where(i => i.id == id).Select(task => new CopyTaskModel()
            {
               NewTaskName = task.Name,
               TaskID = task.id,
               ProjectId = task.ProjectId
            }).FirstOrDefault();
            return PartialView("CopyTask", tmp);
        }

        public ActionResult CopyTask(CopyTaskModel model)
        {
            var context = new pcloudEntities();

            var task = context.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == model.TaskID);
            if (isUnique(model.NewTaskName, model.ProjectId))
            {
                context.Detach(task);
                task.ProjectId = model.ProjectId;
                task.Name = model.NewTaskName;
                context.Tasks.AddObject(task);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("TasksList", "Task", new { projectID = model.ProjectId });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Name is not unique");
                return PartialView("CopyTask", model);
            }
        }
```

As you can see i tried to return the error by doing ModelState.AddModelError. However, the modal window still closes and it renders the partial view outside of the modal window.

Can anyone suggest how I can implement the error pop up from the modal view?

Thank you

Comment: What needs to be unique? That's not clear from your code.

Comment: the IsUnique function I did not include because its not really relevant to this question. Its just a boolean function that checks if the task name exists in the project with projectID and returns true if it does. 

My question is how do I display an error inside the modal window if isUnique returns false?

Comment: I know, but what you are doing is wrong. You should check if model.NewTaskName is unique, not task.Name.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Thank you. However, this doesnt answer my question. Thank you for pointing out that bit though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it like that. You need to use a Remote validation. Here is how you can do it.

You define your Kendo Window like this **(UPDATED)**:

```
@Html.Kendo().Window().Name("CopyTaskWindow")
    .Title("Copy Task")
    .Modal(true).Width(400)
    .Draggable().Iframe(false)
    .Visible(false)
    .Events(events => events.Refresh("onRefresh")) // add a new event here...

function onRefresh(e) {
    // this is to make sure client validation works in the window...
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#CopyTaskWindow"));        
    // UPDATE: This will cause the validation to occur only on submit. 
    // But, as I explained in the comments, it won't work for remote validation...
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        onsubmit: true
    });

    var form = $("#CopyTaskWindow").find('#copyTaskForm');
    form.submit(function () {
        if (form.validate().valid()) {
            var wnd = $("#CopyTaskWindow").data("kendoWindow");
            wnd.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Then, in your Model, you use a `RemoteAttribute` on the property that needs to be validated for uniqueness like this (I'm assuming the NewTaskName has to be unique, even though from your code it's not clear what you want to do):

```
public class CopyTaskModel
{
    [Remote("IsUnique", "YourControllerName", ErrorMessage = "The Task Name already exists.")]
    public string NewTaskName { get; set; }
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you add the validation error message to your Partial View:

```
@model pManager.Models.CopyTaskModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("CopyTask", "Task", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "copyTaskForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.TaskID)
    <div style="float: left; width: 48%;">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewTaskName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewTaskName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewTaskName)
        </div>
     </div>

     // The rest of your Partial View... 
 }
```

And, in your Controller, you'll have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CopyTask(CopyTaskModel model)
{
    var context = new pcloudEntities();

    var task = context.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == model.TaskID);

    context.Detach(task);
    task.ProjectId = model.ProjectId;
    task.Name = model.NewTaskName;
    context.Tasks.AddObject(task);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("TasksList", "Task", new { projectID = model.ProjectId });
}
```

And, the new Action for the Remote validation:

```
public ActionResult IsUnique(NewTaskCopy model)
{
    var isUnique = IsUnique(model.NewTaskName, model.ProjectId);

    return Json(isUnique, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: hank you! This works except for one issue: for some reason even when validation fails the modal window still closes. It seems that form.validate().valid() evaluates to true even when IsUnique returns true . When I click the button to open the modal window again i see the validation message.

Comment: Actually, `form.validate().valid()` does not work for Remote validation, I just included that in case you have other validations in your form. It doesn't work, because remote validation is asynchronous. But, you should get the validation error message on key-up or when you leave the text box. If that's not the case, it could be a browser issue. What browser are you using, and what version of jQuery validation?

Comment: I'm not sure what I was seeing earlier, but it works exactly as you described. Thank you, this solved my problem! However, do you think its possible to also do the validation only on submit? Doing a unique check on every keystroke seems a bit slow...

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that for a remote validation in a window. Because, in case of not having any validation errors, you want the window to be closed, right? But, you can't do that, because as I said, remote validation is asynchronous. The form doesn't wait for the remote validation result to come back from the server, that's why `form.validate().valid()` is always true. But, you can do that in a regular View. See my updated answer.